# sumproduct, fix one array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

I have two columns I do the sumproduct operation on them this way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(I37:I61, **D37:D61**)
```

and it works perfectly well - I put the result **in the cell I8**

but when I copy this function to cell J8

it transfers to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(J37:J61, **E37:E61**)
```

I want TO FIX one array, so my function would look like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(J37:J61, D37:D61)
```

I hope it's clear what do I want to achieve :)

are there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about google spreadsheet, but in microsoft Excel you would need to use below formula for ur use. I think same will work in Google Spreadsheet too.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(I37:I61, $D37:$D61)
```

Notice '$' which says not to translate D when you do copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

I would used named ranges to avoid any confusion. Here are the steps
1) Select the range D37:D61 
2) give the name a range by tying in a name to the left hand side of the fx near where you insert the formula
3) let's call that range DATA1
4) then use the formula =SUMPRODUCT(I37:I61, DATA1)
5) when you copy this formula over to next cells it should show as =SUMPRODUCT(J37:J61, DATA1)

Let me know how you get on.